# what return 'windows.location.pathname'?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, pathname

I tested something with the function window.locatin.pathname.

This is my js script:

```js
var location = window.location.pathname;

console.log(location); // -> /de/immobilien-auf-mallorca/

if(location == "/de/immobilien-auf-mallorca"){
  console.log('true'); //doesn't work! It is not true???
}else{
  console.log('false'); //Output in my console    
}
```

I think that my var `'location'` is a string and contains this string '`/de/immobilien-auf-mallorca`'.

But if I include an if statement (`if location = /de/immobilien-auf-mallorca`) I don't come into the first part of my if statement. (Take a look above)

I don't know why maybe my variable isn't a string?!

Maybe someone knows more about this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `if(decodeURIComponent(location) == "/de/immobilien-auf-mallorca"){`

Comment: Tried your code.Works fine for me.

Comment: @cgee Check `length` of the pathname and the length of the string to compare

Comment: @Tushar the string of window.location = 28 and in the if statement = 27.. but why???

Comment: @cgee Can't say from here maybe hidden characters in it, try `trim` on location

Comment: I forgot a slash -.- .... But thanks!

Comment: Try a variable name other than `location`.

Comment: `location` variable will work as long as you don't use it in the global scope. 
`(function(){ var location = window.location.pathname; console.log(location); console.log(window.location); })()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen a very particular reserved keyword to log ---> location, location defaults to window.location, which is an object.
The solution is pretty simple, replace your variable name to something like "myLocation", that will make the trick.

```
var myLocation = window.location.pathname;

console.log(myLocation); // -> /de/immobilien-auf-mallorca

if(myLocation == "/de/immobilien-auf-mallorca"){
  console.log('true'); //It's going to work....
}else{
  console.log('false'); //Output in my console    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
var locationVar = window.location.pathname;

   console.log(locationVar); // -> /de/immobilien-auf-mallorca

 if(locationVar == "/de/immobilien-auf-mallorca"){
      console.log('true'); //doesn't work! It is not true???
    }else{
      console.log('false'); //Output in my console    
    }
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: _window.location.pathname is an object._ no, it's string. Try following in console `> typeof window.location.pathname
"string"
> typeof location.pathname
"string"`

Comment: If I try it I got the message, that location is undefined.

Comment: Dont't forget to declare location variable. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Shahid Now `var location = window.location.pathname;` and you're accessing `location.pathname` which will be `undefined`

Comment: @Tushar your are right. Actuall problem is with the variable name location. I have updated the my answer.

Comment: @Shahid same! Thanks.